# Webscraping a site with a 'Load More' button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape a website that has a 'Load More' button with Selenium and BeautifulSoup. I have gotten my script to click the load more button and load the rest of the content, but I am having issues scraping the content into a json file.  Here is my script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://smarthistory.org/americas-before-1900/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/rawlins/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_num = 0

while driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#load-more-cc-objects'):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#load-more-cc-objects').click()
    page_num += 1
    print("getting page number "+str(page_num))
    time.sleep(1)

html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

data = [] 

# Parse HTML, close browser
page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"mb-8 hover-zoom tablescraper-selected-row opacity-100"})

for container in containers:
    item = {}
    item['type'] = "Course Material"
    item['title'] = container.find('h5', {'class' : 'm-0 mt-4 text-grey-darker text-normal leading-tight hover-connect'}).text.strip()
    item['link'] = container.a["href"]
    item['source'] = "Smarthistory"
    item['base_url'] = "https://smarthistory.org"
    item['license'] = "Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike"
    data.append(item) # add the item to the list

with open("smarthistory-2.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)

browser.quit()
```

My expected output is something like this

```
[
    {
        "type": "Course Material",
        "title": "Impressionism as optical realism: Monet",
        "link": "https://smarthistory.org/impressionism-optical-realism-monet/",
        "source": "Smarthistory",
        "base_url": "https://smarthistory.org",
        "license": "Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike"
    },
    {
        "type": "Course Material",
        "title": "Impressionism: painting modern life",
        "link": "https://smarthistory.org/painting-modern-life/",
        "source": "Smarthistory",
        "base_url": "https://smarthistory.org",
        "license": "Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike"
    }
]
```

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/selenium-click-button/

Answer (score 1):

When using Google Chrome's DEV Tools (F12) you can inspect the network traffic. 
Simply go to the Network tab inside the DEV tools whilst being on the website and click on the "Load More" button. 
You should see an request (`object?tag=DDD&page=2`) popping up in the list.
Use the request URL inside a loop to iterate over the pages.
With this way you can get the JSON directly without needing to click a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import json

url = "https://smarthistory.org/americas-before-1900/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_num = 0

########
try:
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#load-more-cc-objects')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#load-more-cc-objects').click()
except:
    pass

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#load-more-cc-objects')
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#load-more-cc-objects').click()
        page_num += 1
        print("getting page number "+str(page_num))

        #sleep(randint(2, 10))
        time.sleep(1)

    except:
        print("Reached bottom of page")
        break
##########




html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')


data = []

# Parse HTML, close browser
page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
containers = page_soup.findAll(
    "div", {"class": "mb-8 hover-zoom"})

for container in containers:
    item = {}
    item['type'] = "Course Material"
    item['title'] = container.find(
        'h5', {'class': 'm-0 mt-4 text-grey-darker text-normal leading-tight hover-connect'}).text.strip()
    item['link'] = container.a["href"]
    item['source'] = "Smarthistory"
    item['base_url'] = "https://smarthistory.org"
    item['license'] = "Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike"
    data.append(item)  # add the item to the list

with open("smarthistory-2.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)

driver.quit()
```